# How to add a new property to a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I've searched the questions here and on Google and I find answers, but they don't seem to work in my code.  I want to add a new PhotoIndex property to a JSON object in AngularJS.  I have the code below which works (the photos appear), but doesn't have the PhotoIndex property:

```
$scope.GetImagesOnBar = function ()
{
    var photos = $scope.$parent.Photos;
    return photos;
};
```

When I try to add the PhotoIndex property to the JSON array object named photos, it breaks the code and the photos no longer appear.  Can you tell me why?

```
$scope.GetImagesOnBar = function ()
{
    var photos = $scope.$parent.Photos;
    var index = 0;
    for (var i = $scope.ImageFirst; i <= $scope.ImageLast; i++)
    {
        photos[i].PhotoIndex = index;
        index = index + 1;
    }
    return photos;
};
```

Comment: "breaks the code" means what error message?

Comment: I am not aware of an error message.  I just see that the images no longer appear.  No worky.

Comment: Check the browser console.

Comment: There is nothing about `json`

Comment: FYI, you have either JSON or an object. JSON is a data format, an object is what you actually manipulate in JavaScript. Next, is each elements of `photos` an object? Have you looked in your console for any errors?

Comment: OK.  More details.  I built a Web API in ASP.NET.  it returns JSON objects or whatever word you want to call it, to my AngularJS code on the lcient.  I checked the console (I've never used that before) and it does have an error much to my surprise.  It said:  Error: $scope.$parent.Photos[i] is undefined.  I don't know why.  Maybe it will work if I use angular.foreach.

Comment: @SteveGaines Your server sends you JSON, Angular parses it into objects. And you'll get that error if a) `$scope.parent.Photos` isn't an array or b) you've gone outside of the range of that array. If you check the length of the array (`photos.length`) you'll be able to determine if you've gone outside of it.

Comment: Are you able to create a plunker that demonstrates the problem? There's a lot more information needed here to be able to deduce the problem, especially when dealing with Angular (like how it's being used in the DOM, what photos is - an object, an array, etc?)

Comment: To everyone who replied, thank you.  Your comments helped me to find a solution.  It wasn't a direct solution, but it works.  I used the angular foreach loop instead.  See the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks for the comments.  I checked the console as suggested and saw the error "$scope.$parent.Photos[i] is undefined". I don't know why, but I decide to try angular.foreach and that worked.  See the solution below.

```
$scope.GetImagesOnBar = function ()
{
    var index = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.$parent.Photos, function (photo)
    {
        photo.PhotoIndex = index;
        index = index + 1;
    });
    return $scope.$parent.Photos;
};
```